# Open a PDF file in a new tab in .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a button that generates a PDF file. I am trying to have the PDF file open in a new window but so far I have been unsuccessful.

Button code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("/DetailToPdf/"+ comb.Id, "Combined")'"
                        data-placement="top" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-content="PDF" data-trigger="hover">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
```

Relevant code of my controller:

```
public ActionResult DetailToPdf(long id = 0)
    {
        ...

        //Convert HTML string to PDF
        PdfDocument document = htmlConverter.Convert(htmlText, baseUrl);
        
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

        //Save and close the PDF document 
        document.Save(stream);

        document.Close(true);

        return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/pdf", model.Id + "_approval.pdf");
    }
```

Things that I have tried so far:

Adding `formtarget="_blank"` to the button tag

Adding `target="_blank"` to the button tag

Adding `, new { target = "_blank" }` to the url.action

Neither of those seemed to do the trick. What am I missing/ doing wrong here?

Comment: Your browser is likely configured to download PDFs rather than view them.

Comment: @phuzi Not sure if I understand. Right now it opens the PDF in the current window. From there I can download it if I waned to but it does not download by default. It just opens it in the current tab.

Comment: Ah, you didn't explain that in your question... Just noticed that you're trying to add the `target` attribute to a `button` element, you may have more success using an anchor element (`a`) where the `target` attribute is actually [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes#:~:text=one%20specified%20instead.-,target,-%3Ca%3E%2C%20%3Carea%3E%2C%20%3Cbase)

Comment: @phuzi thank, I managed to make it work with the a tag and made that one look like the other buttons instead.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by changing the button tag to an a tag:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("/DetailToPdf/"+ comb.Id, "Combined")"  class="btn btn-warning" target="_blank"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
```

I will leave the question open a bit longer to see if people know a better way to go about this or not.